# How property-invariance is imposed to neural nets?

Tags: machine-learning, symmetry

I was wondering how specific symmetries or constraints such as property-invariance transformation are imposed on any (deep) neural net when they are trained.

I'll appreciate it if anyone can aware me of the relevant researches in this direction.

Comment: Do you have specific "properties" in mind?  Convolution NNs are famously translation equivariant.  Achieving other symmetries is harder: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1909.12057.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the paper! Shift-invariance was the first example that occurs to me. In fact, in terms of object detection and in particularly the convolutional nets, I believe any Affine transformation should in principle keep the result intact, although there might be no guarantee on better performance.